# PHP include_once doesn't work

Tags: php, include

Hi guys this is my code:

```
<?php
    include_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."itk/gestionale_ore_lavoro/classi/utenti_joomla.class.php");
    include_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."itk/gestionale_ore_lavoro/classi/riempi_tag.class.php");
    $select = new riempi_tag();
?>
```

It doesn't work; but if I delete this two command

```
<?php
    include_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."itk/gestionale_ore_lavoro/classi/riempi_tag.class.php");
    $select = new riempi_tag();
?>
```

it works! Does someone knows why? There are no error inside "riempi_tag.class.php"

Comment: Do you have errors turned on? Perhaps there is a problem with the first inclusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` does not return a trailing slash, try:

```
<?php
    include_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/itk/gestionale_ore_lavoro/classi/utenti_joomla.class.php");
    include_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/itk/gestionale_ore_lavoro/classi/riempi_tag.class.php");
    $select = new riempi_tag();
?>
```